# Subtracting audio channels

Tags: sound

Is there a function that takes right channel of audio and combines it with inverted left channel of audio?
Do not confuse inverted with reversed.

The following does not work since it does not allow negative arguments.

```
AudioChannelMix[someaudio, {"Mono", {1, -1}}]
```

`AudioChannelCombine` is also of no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = ExampleData[{"Audio", "Bird"}, "Audio"];
{lc, rc} = AudioChannelSeparate[a];
Audio[(AudioData[rc] - AudioData[lc])/2] // AudioNormalize
```

Comment: I do not understand why they did not integrate it in the `AudioChannelMix`. It is standard of all audio editing software to be able mixing channels also with negative weights. Too long code for a trivial task.